# Using the same instance on different python file

Tags: python, class, tkinter, instance

I've two class one of them GUI class the other is the background. I need to trigger a function in GUI class but i got **TypeError: App.enable_gui() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'** error.
I called the function like that

```
   app = App()
   app.enable_gui()
```

but it tries to create a new instance and in my App class it needs to a parameter to create instance i guess therefore it doesn't create. But i want to use the opened GUI therefore existing instance. How can i do that?

```
class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('Instagram Bot')
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.bot = None  # initialize bot attribute to None
        self.style = ttk.Style()....
    def enable_gui(self):
        self.compare_profile_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL, text="Compare Profile")
    self.following_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL, text="Send Requests to Following")
```

Comment: Are you sure you wrote `app.enable_gui()` and not `App.enable_gui()`? The code in the question shouldn't get that error.

Comment: Why don't you use the already created instance to call the `.enable_gui()`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what is look like?

You have tooo many namespaces.

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('Instagram Bot')
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.bot = None  # initialize bot attribute to None
        self.compare_profile_button = Button(self, text='Click', command=self.enable_gui)
        self.compare_profile_button.pack()
        self.following_button = Button(self, command=self.enable_gui)
        self.following_button.pack()
        self.style = ttk.Style() 
    def enable_gui(self):
        self.compare_profile_button.config(state=NORMAL, text="Compare Profile")
        self.following_button.config(state=NORMAL, text="Send Requests to Following")

root =Tk()
app = App(root)
app.enable_gui
```

root.mainloop()

Screenshot:

[image]